# How to use CD-HIT to filter protein sequences dataset by certain similarity threshold?

Tags: clustering, sequence

I am looking at using CD-HIT to efficiently **filter my protein sequences dataset by a similarity threshold of 70% (cut-off).** More precisely, what I want to achieve is that for all the remaining sequences after filtering, all pairwise sequence similarity scores that can be computed are less than 70%.

Does that mean that I **should run CD-HIT on my dataset with similarity threshold=70%** (rest of the settings at default values), and **then just keep only the "representative" sequences from the resulting cluster files**? I have read the guide (http://weizhongli-lab.org/lab-wiki/doku.php?id=cd-hit-user-guide) but I am still not sure of how to use the output.

Linking to the above, how would CD-HIT handle this scenario below or similar ones like this:

- assuming seq. similarity threshold=70%
- sim.(seqA, seqB) = 80%
- sim.(seqA,seqC) = 90%
- sim.(seqA,seqD) = 65%
- sim.(seqA, seqE) = 60%
- sim.(seqD, seqE) = 50%
- => here, would the method keep just seqE, seqD in the output as sequences satisfying the threshold?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't follow your question. The sequences `seqD` and `seqE` do not fall into the `seqA|seqB|seqC` cluster, nor do the fall into the same cluster, so you will have three clusters, with the type sequences `seqA`,`seqD` and `seqE`. But that's not your question is it?